# Starting service from a class extending applicaiton android

Tags: android

I am trying to call a service from a class extending android. The service in turn is starting some threads. When i m stopping the service from list of running services, the `onDestroy()` of the service is not getting called.

But when i m stopping the service which is started from an activity its `onDestroy()` method is being called.

What is the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

because stop service 'kills the service' and interrupts its life cycle,but when you stop it from the your application, it continue its life cycle and go into destroy staus.